# A set with measure $0$ has a translate containing no rational number.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, rational-numbers

> Suppose $E$ is a set with measure $0$. Show there exists $t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $E+t$ contains no rational number.

My idea is to find an interval in $E$, then we can get a contradiction. I try to begin with a point in $E$ and then consider if there is an interval containing this point in $E$. But I don't know how to start.

Maybe, we can go by contradiction.  If $E+t$ contains a rational number $q_t$ for every $t\in \Bbb R$, then we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Q}$, $t\mapsto q_t$.  But this idea leads nowhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Another approach.* By replacing $E$ by $\bigcup_{r\in\Bbb{Q}} (r+E)$, we may assume WLOG that $E$ is invariant under rational translation. Then $t+E$ contains a rational number if and only if $t+E$ contains *all* rational numbers.

Now can you show that $t+E$ does not contain $0$ for some $t$?

Comment: If $0\in t+E, \forall t$, then $-t\in E, \forall t$. That means $\mathbb{R}\subseteq E$, contradiction.

Comment: Ooh, nice, I like this one! Note the duality between "a countable intersection of measure-1 sets has measure 1" (used in my answer) and "a countable union of measure-0 sets has measure 0" (used in this answer). +1

Comment: Nice proof. I was puzzled by this Q.

Answer (score 9):

You can also show that $Z:=\bigcup\limits_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}\,(q-E)$ has measure $0$. For a real number $t\notin Z$, can $t+E$ intersect the rationals?

Comment: What if the statement of the question is generalized to the following: _"Suppose $Q$ and $E$ are two sets (of reals) both with measure zero. Show that there exists a $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $E+t$ contains no point of $Q$."_ So in this generalization, $Q$ may be uncountable. Is this more general statement true or false?

Comment: Without the restriction that one set be countable, the claim is false.  Let $K$ be the usual Cantor set.  Take $Q$ and $E$ to be $\bigcup\limits_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\,(K+i)$.  Then, both $Q$ and $E$ are of measure $0$ (noting that $K-K=[-1,1]$).  However, $Q-E=\mathbb{R}$, whence for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $t+E$ intersects $Q$.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: For a fixed real number $r$, let $S_r$ be the set of shifts which avoid $r$: $$S_r=\{t: r\not\in E+t\}.$$

- If $E$ has measure zero, what can you say about $S_r$?
- The rationals are countable, and $$\{t: E+t\cap\mathbb{Q}=\emptyset\}=\bigcap_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}S_q.$$ Do you see why the intersection of countably many sets with the property above is nonempty?

Comment: I devised a proof but failed to complete it,;will you please help me complete it???Proof: Since $m(E)=0\implies m(E+t)=0\forall t\in \Bbb R$. Assume that $E+t$ contains a rational number for each $t\in \Bbb R$ .It is obvious that $E+t_i $ and $E+t_j$ contains a common rational since rational numbers are countable.

Comment: But I am unable to derive a contradiction from here?Do you mind helping me out

Comment: @BobWilson That route doesn't really work - in particular, all you can derive is that there is some rational $q$ and uncountably many reals $t_i$ ($i\in I$) such that $q\in E+t_i$. But that doesn't in itself lead to a contradiction. You need to use some properties of measure. Look at my answer: what can you conclude about the measure of the set $S_r$? (Note that $S_r$ is **not** a translate of $E$ - read the definition carefully!)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I'm not quite sure how to go about this, how does one interpret the sets $S_r$?

Comment: @nolemonnomelon Given a real number $r$, some translates of $E$ "avoid" $r$ (= don't contain $r$ as an element) and other translates don't. $S_r$ is the set of ways to translate $E$ so that you don't wind up containing $r$. For instance, if $E$ is the Cantor set then ${1\over 2}\in S_1$ since if I shift $E$ over by $1\over 2$ the "middle gap" includes $1$.